Roared to lusty purpose
Another question related to "A Christmas Carol". Having the following sentence:

If the good Saint Dunstan had but nipped the Evil Spirit’s nose with a
touch of such weather as that, instead of using his familiar weapons,
then indeed he would have roared to lusty purpose.

Could you please deconstruct this construction and provide some more examples which employs similar constructions? I read some explanation (there are but a few) on the Internet but still can't understand how this construction works. So the Devil roars but why would it be his "lusty purpose"?

It's archaic English. To do something with X purpose means to do that thing with the effect or manner described by X. Lusty means strong or powerful, so if St Dunstan had nipped the Evil Spirit's nose with very cold weather, then the Evil Spirit would have roared strongly, powerfully, or loudly.

I don't think questions about older forms of English should be downvoted. Not upvoted makes sense, as not being helpful to the large majority of learners.  I doubt that a learner could have answered the question for themselves by consulting a dictionary.

I think there needs to be a cut off.  I've proposed 1847, the publication of Jane Eyre.  Anything before Jane Eyre isn't really useful for "learning English".  That's intended to be generous. I'd still want to read Jane Eyre in an edition that had a decent set of end-notes.  But I wouldn't downvote even if someone was asking about Chaucer or Beowulf.

I'd argue against any cutoff, since we're hardly inundated with such questions.  Just perhaps a set of tags indicating the century or the period involved, or one non-contemporary or archaic tag to rule them all. It's possible to set an "ignore" setting on tags, I think, though I've never tried it.

So if I have a question about archaic English this website is wrong? How about https://english.stackexchange.com? Or it is an offtopic on the whole StackExchange?

Plenty of questions about older forms of English on ELU.

Since you have asked for a "deconstruction"...
The preposition to can be used to introduce a result or effect.

The palace staff polished the tarnished silver to a bright lustre.

The result of the polishing was the bright lustre.
"Lusty" had other meanings besides "concupiscient" : powerful, energetic, mighty, etc.
And "purpose" there means something like "intention".
The Evil One would have been provoked by the nose-nipping to roar,  the  roar leading to, or presaging, some ferocious act.
